# Looping through a JSONArray to convert Strings into Objects

Tags: android, arrays, loops, arraylist, fragment

I currently have a method which creates a URL from a user input, sends a HTTP request to get a JSONArray and then converts the JSONArray into an ArrayList. For some reason the loop which is meant to add one of each JSONObject only copies the same one 10 times, despite the fact that the loop counter doesn't tell it to do so. Obviously I'm missing something but here is the code below:

MainActivity

```
public ArrayList<Eatery> fillArray(String url) {


    String line;
    Eatery eatery = new Eatery("null","null","null","null","null",
            "null","null","null","null","null");
    ArrayList<Eatery> eateryList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (getConnection() == true) {
        try {

            URL urlFinal = createURL(url);
            HttpURLConnection postcodeConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlFinal.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(postcodeConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);

            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jo.getString("id");
                    String businessName = jo.getString("BusinessName");
                    String addressLine1 = jo.getString("AddressLine1");
                    String addressLine2 = jo.getString("AddressLine2");
                    String addressLine3 = jo.getString("AddressLine3");
                    String postcode = jo.getString("PostCode");
                    String ratingValue = jo.getString("RatingValue");
                    String ratingDate = jo.getString("RatingDate");
                    String lati = jo.getString("Latitude");
                    String longi = jo.getString("Longitude");
                    eatery.setId(id);
                    eatery.setBusinessName(businessName);
                    eatery.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
                    eatery.setAddressLine2(addressLine2);
                    eatery.setAddressLine3(addressLine3);
                    eatery.setPostcode(postcode);
                    eatery.setRatingValue(ratingValue);
                    eatery.setRatingDate(ratingDate);
                    eatery.setLati(lati);
                    eatery.setLati(longi);
                    eateryList.add(eatery);
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Toast nameToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            nameToast.show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast nameToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: No Active Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        nameToast.show();
    }

    return (eateryList);
}
```

Internal Methods:

```
public boolean getConnection(){

    conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    networkInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean connected;
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
    {
        connected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        connected = false;
    }
    return connected;
}

public URL createURL(String searchType) {

    String URLstart = "http://sandbox.kriswelsh.com/hygieneapi/hygiene.php?op=";
    searchType = searchType.replace(" ", "%20");
    String finalURL = URLstart.concat(searchType);
    URL nameURL = null;
    try {
        nameURL = new URL(finalURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return nameURL;
}
```

The above are inside ActivityMain and are currently being called from a fragment which takes the user input from a EditText box, adds it to the fillArray method, and then returns the result into another ArrayList instantiated on the Fragment.

Fragment Code Below:

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment {

EditText enterName;
Button searchNameButton;
TableLayout nameTableLayout;
TextView testTextView, tv;
TableRow tr;
ArrayList<Eatery> nameEateryList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_search_fragment, container, false);

    enterName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.enterNameText);
    searchNameButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchNameButton);
    testTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
    nameTableLayout = (TableLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.NameTableLayout);

    searchNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String nameSearch = enterName.getText().toString().trim();
            String nameURLKey = "s_name&name=";
            nameURLKey = nameURLKey.concat(nameSearch);

            //Grab ArrayList
            nameEateryList = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).fillArray(nameURLKey);

            for(int i = 0; i < nameEateryList.size(); i++) {

                tv = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                tr = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                //Create Table Counter
                int turn = nameTableLayout.getChildCount();
                turn += 1;
                String turnString = turn + "";

                //Add TextView
                tv.setText(nameEateryList.get(i).eateryToString());
                tv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
                tr.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#557788"));
                tv.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
                tr.addView(tv);
                nameTableLayout.addView(tr);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
   }
```

For some reason, when this cycles through the ArrayList and copies the results into my Fragment all the results are the same. The code runs and the ArrayList is filled but it seems to be failing to cycle through the ArrayList. Been stuck on this for a while but I just can't figure out exactly what is causing the ArrayList to copy the same object repeatedly rather than cycle through all the results. I hope this makes sense. If any further information is needed then I can certainly provide more code. This is quite a specific issue and I couldn't identify another thread that had this exact problem, apologies if this answer exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `Eatery` object for every iteration of for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    Eatery eatery = new Eatery("null","null","null","null","null",
        "null","null","null","null","null");

    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = jo.getString("id");
    String businessName = jo.getString("BusinessName");
    String addressLine1 = jo.getString("AddressLine1");
    String addressLine2 = jo.getString("AddressLine2");
    String addressLine3 = jo.getString("AddressLine3");
    String postcode = jo.getString("PostCode");
    String ratingValue = jo.getString("RatingValue");
    String ratingDate = jo.getString("RatingDate");
    String lati = jo.getString("Latitude");
    String longi = jo.getString("Longitude");
    eatery.setId(id);
    eatery.setBusinessName(businessName);
    eatery.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
    eatery.setAddressLine2(addressLine2);
    eatery.setAddressLine3(addressLine3);
    eatery.setPostcode(postcode);
    eatery.setRatingValue(ratingValue);
    eatery.setRatingDate(ratingDate);
    eatery.setLati(lati);
    eatery.setLati(longi);
    eateryList.add(eatery);
}
```

The problem you are facing is because you are adding only a single object to your list for every loop iteration and value for that object will be the last values you set to the `Eatery` object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure I come across as a complete moron for not recognising the problem but I'd been looking for a solution for several hours yesterday to no avail. Very simple solution and your response is very much appreciated. Have a nice day!